# Google Analytics on AMP-Pages without cookies

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, amp-html, amp-analytics

**Is it possible to use Google Analytics on AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) Pages without cookies?**

If yes, how should it be configured?

Because of the General Data Protection Regulation (EU) 2016/679 (GDPR) the user of a website has to give its consent to store (tracking)-data on users computer. We want to use Google Analytics on AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) anyway. Currently we doing it with `<amp-pixel>` and the analytics API, but this is only a superficial tracking. Is it possible to use `<amp-analytics>` and disable cookie like the "desktop-version" of the analytics-script?

Thanks, for help

Answer (score 0):

This might help: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-consent/
The docs provide an example of how `amp-consent` might be used with `amp-analytics`